# htaccess - Redirect with exception

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a webpage where I'm going to move the old page to a subdirectory, while installing ExpressionEngine on the root. However, I want to redirect users to the subdirectory now. While I'm still able to build the new ExpressionEngine site on the root. Is this possible?

Basically, whenever a user navigates to http://www.mywebsite.com, I want to redirect them to http://www.mywebsite.com/old

But, when I navigate to http://www.mywebsite.com/new, I actually want to redirect it to http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php, because ExpressionEngine is installed on the root.
The idea is that when the page is done, I just have to remove these rules from htaccess and that's that.

As of now I've only got this rule set up:

```
redirect /index.php http://www.mywebsite.com/old/
```

This creates a problem because /index.php is the actual ExpressionEngine index.php, which is the default page of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?$ /old [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.+$ /index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Hmm, this gives me an Internal Server Error. I've tried several variations of this code as well, still gives me the same error.

Comment: Actually, it worked when I just removed the 'RewriteRule ^.+$ /index.php [L,NC]'. And that last edit also worked! :)

Comment: Ok great, hope that is how you wanted rewrites to happen.

Comment: Yes it is! :) Now, I just need to read up on how the heck this actually works!

Comment: Sure I can just give summary here. Rule 1: Matches if current URL is `^$` (i.e. `http://domain.com`) and then makes an external redirect to `/old` (using R flag). Rule 2: Using `RewriteCond` it checks whether request is not for a real file or dir and if not them it silently rewrites that to `/index.php`.

Comment: Fabulous! That actually makes sense! All the articles I've read about this just assumes I already know what half of this stuff means. Makes a lot more sense now! :)